# Angular : ngFor items and append a char for all items except the last item

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6, angular2-template

I am looping my data list and displaying in the view in spans :

```
 <span  *ngFor="let d of myData"> {{d.name}} ,</span>
```

As you can see , I am adding a comma '**,**' in the end of every item to obtain a coherent view

this results my in this appearance :

```
AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,
```

My problem is with **the last comma which I want to automatically remove.

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `last` local variable, like so:

```
<span *ngFor="let d of myData; last as isLast"> {{d.name}} <span *ngIf="!isLast">,</span></span>
```

[Readmore](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)

Answer (score 0):

user the the last operator (let lastItem as last), to detect the last item and display only if it is not last item.

```
<span  *ngFor="let dof myData; last as isLast"> {{d.name}} 
    <span *ngIf="!isFirst"> , </span>
</span>
```